# convert grouped data with groupby to dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

how can i do to convert my grouped data to data frame. Each group in one dataframe? 
i did this to group my data 
I wrote:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal' : ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                               'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed' : [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
df.groupby('Animal')
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Two dataframes?

Comment: yes 2 dataframes

Comment: `{idx: grp for idx, grp in df.groupby('Animal')}` will create a dict with `DataFrame` per animal

Comment: `df1, df2 = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Animal'))).values()`. Though I'd stick with the dict as the container if you need an arbitrary number of DataFrames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df

   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
```

Instead of groupby you can use .loc to get desire results in separate dataframes

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Animal'] == 'Falcon'].reset_index(drop = True)
df1

   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0

df2 = df.loc[df['Animal'] == 'Parrot'].reset_index(drop = True)
df2

   Animal  Max Speed
0  Parrot       24.0
1  Parrot       26.0
```

You can use loop for multiple dataframes

*P.S. Parrot and Falcon are the Birds ;-)*

Answer (score 3):

Use [`dict` comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
animals = {idx: grp for idx, grp in df.groupby('Animal')}
```

Access with the 'Animal' as the key like:

```
animals['Falcon']
```

[out]

```
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
```

Comment: `animals = dict((*df.groupby('Animal'),))` Because that isn't confusing at all (-;

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
dfs = []
for i in df.groupby('Animal'):
    dfs.append(i[1])

print(dfs[0])

   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0

print(dfs[1])
   Animal  Max Speed
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0
```